# Gulp.JS, one source to a dynamic number of destinations

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have one JavaScript source file I am processing that I want to end up in two or more destination folders. Piping to multiple destinations work if I chain the pipes, but not if I add it to a stream one at a time. This prevents me from making the number of destination folders dynamic.

For example doing the following works

```
var rebundle = function() {
  var stream = bundler.bundle();
  stream = stream.pipe(source("bundled.js"));

  stream.pipe(gulp.dest(dests[0]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dests[1]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dests[2]));

  return stream;
};
```

But the following works inconsistently. Sometimes one folder fails to output, other times it does but is missing some contents.

```
var rebundle = function() {
  var stream = bundler.bundle();
  stream = stream.pipe(source("bundled.js"));

  dests.map(function(d) {
    stream.pipe(gulp.dest(d));
  });

  return stream;
};
```

In short, is there a way to modify it to allow for a dynamic amount of destinations when starting from one source folder cleanly in one file?

Versions

- gulp 3.9
- browserify 9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each invokation of `stream.pipe()` returns a new stream. You have to apply each following invokation of `.pipe()` to the previously returned stream.

You're doing it right when you do `stream = stream.pipe(source("bundled.js"))`, but then in your `dest.map()` callback you're just adding one pipe after another to the same stream. That means you're creating lots of new streams, but those never get returned from you task, so gulp doesn't wait for them to finish.

You have to store the returned stream each time, so that it's used in the next iteration:

```
dests.map(function(d) {
  stream = stream.pipe(gulp.dest(d));
});
```

Comment: Why are we not concerned about storing the value that `.map(...)` returns in this case? Also how about we simply use a `forEach` loop in case of a `.map`?